# Why is System.Type.IsPublic returning as false?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a little console application that I'm tinkering with just to learn something new.

In the code below, in `Console.WirteLine()`, if I test `t.IsAbstract`, or `t.IsSealed`, my output is `AbstractClass true`, or `SealedClass true` respectively. All others return `false` as I expect.

However, if I test `t.IsPublic`, everything, including both `PublicClass` and `PublicInterface` return `false`.  **Why is that?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Test
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Type[] assemblyTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type t in assemblyTypes)
                Console.WriteLine(t.Name + " " + t.IsPublic);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private class PrivateClass { }

        public class PublicClass { }

        protected class ProtectedClass { }

        sealed class SealedClass { }

        abstract class AbstractClass { }

        interface myInterface { }

        public interface PublicInterface { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because they are nested inside of `Test`.

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.ispublic.aspx): true if the Type is declared public and **is not a nested type**; otherwise, false.

As @Jeb's answer and the docs suggest, `typeof(PublicClass)` should have a value of true for the [IsNestedPublic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isnestedpublic.aspx) property

Answer (score 3):

It's not public outside the assembly...[IsNestedPublic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isnestedpublic.aspx) should be true though..